# Can "which one" be used for people?

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns

Consider this example :

> "I saw one of the Jones brothers yesterday"
>   "Yes?**Which one/Whom** did you see?

I think "whom" is correct because I am referring to people, but which one also feels correct to me. Which of these is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**which one** is the usual way to ask that question referring to one of several possibilities.  **whom**, or nowadays **who** (the objective case form *whom* is falling out of use in speech) is a more general question: *tell me who you saw* not *tell me which one of them you saw*.  Only from context would it be understood to mean "which of them".